# pandas df apply condition on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a df that looks like this:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'master_feature':['ab',float('NaN'),float('NaN')],
    'feature':[float('NaN'),float('NaN'),'pq'],
    'epic':[float('NaN'),'fg',float('NaN')]})
```

I want to create a new column named `promoted` from the columns master_feature, epic, and feature:

value of `promoted` will be :

- `master feature` if adjacent `master_feature` column value is not
  null.
- `feature` if adjacent `feature` column value is not null ,and likewise
  for `epic`

something like:

```
df.promoted = 'master feature' if not pd.isnull(df.master_feature) 
               elseif 'feature' if not pd.isnull(df.feature) 
               elseif 'epic' pd.isnull(df.epic) 
               else 'Na'
```

how can I achieve this using a `df.apply`?
is it much more efficient if I use `np.select`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.select` is the way to go. Try below . . . I think I got the logic correct based on your question. Also, there is some discrepancy in your logic: "feature if adjacent feature column value is not null ,and likewise for epic" is not the same as "elseif 'epic' pd.isnull(df.epic)" So I went with if `df['epic'] is not null then 'epic'` Let me know if that is correct.

```
cond = [~df['master_feature'].isna(), # if master_feater is not null then 'master feater'
        ~df['feature'].isna(), # if feature is not null then 'feature
        ~df['epic'].isna()] # if epic is not null then 'epic'

choice = ['master feature', 
          'feature', 
          'epic']

df['promoted'] = np.select(cond, choice, np.nan)

  master_feature feature epic        promoted
0             ab     NaN  NaN  master feature
1            NaN     NaN   fg            epic
2            NaN      pq  NaN         feature
```

Comment: @DevarshiGoswami OK, does changing the last condition to `df.isna().all(axis=1)` work?

Comment: It works now, this was happening because df['epic'] was missing a tilde for the negation

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with combination of `apply()` and numpy `argmin()`

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'master_feature':['ab',float('NaN'),float('NaN')],
    'feature':[float('NaN'),float('NaN'),'pq'],
    'epic':[float('NaN'),'fg',float('NaN')]})

df.assign(promoted=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: r[np.argmin(r.isna())], axis=1))
```